# I am trying to make this game, but the collision blocks are all spawning at the same position

Tags: python, pygame

```
import time import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def \__init_\_(self, player_x, player_y):
        super().\__init_\_()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("img for sprites\\\\img_9.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (40, 55))
        self.image.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = \[player_x, player_y\]
        self.hop = False
        self.vel_y = 15

    def left(self, self_speed):
        self.rect.centerx -= self_speed

    def right(self, self_speed):
        self.rect.centerx += self_speed

    def up(self, self_speed):
        self.rect.centery -= self_speed

    def down(self, self_speed):
        self.rect.centery += self_speed


pygame.init() wl, wb = 912, 600 window = pygame.display.set_mode((wl, wb))

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")  # You can set a custom name

icon = pygame.image.load("image\\\\InShot_20220211_195228643.jpg")  # Enter file location with name pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# FPS FPS = 60

# Map grass_image = pygame.image.load('img for sprites\\\\grass.png') TILE_SIZE = grass_image.get_width() \* 3

dirt_image = pygame.image.load('img for sprites\\\\dirt.png')

grass_image, dirt_image = pygame.transform.scale(grass_image, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)), \\
                          pygame.transform.scale(dirt_image, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

game_map = \[\['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'\], 
            \['2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2'\], 
            \['1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1'\], 
            \['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\], 
            \['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\], 
            \['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\], 
            \['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\],
            \['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\]\]

# Player player_group = pygame.sprite.Group() px, py = 0, 0  # your player position player = Player(px, py) player_group.add(player) up, down, left, right = True, True, True, True

# block collision_tolerance = 10 block_list = \[\]

running = True clock = pygame.time.Clock() last_time = time.time() bg = pygame.image.load("image\\\\bg2.png").convert() bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1000, 600)) bg_x, bg_y = 0, 0 while running:
    # delta time setup
    dt = time.time() - last_time
    dt \*= FPS
    last_time = time.time()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # window color
    window.fill((128, 128, 128))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    window.blit(bg, (bg_x, bg_y))

    for blocks in block_list:
        if pygame.Rect.colliderect(blocks, player.rect):
            if abs(blocks.right - player.rect.left) \< collision_tolerance:
                left = False
            if abs(blocks.left - player.rect.right) \< collision_tolerance:
                right = False
            if abs(blocks.top - player.rect.bottom) \< collision_tolerance:
                down = False
            if abs(blocks.bottom - player.rect.top) \< collision_tolerance:
                up = False
        else:
            up, down, left, right = True, True, True, True
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), blocks, 3)

    tile_rect = \[\]
    y = 0
    for row in game_map:
        x = 0
        for tile in row:
            if tile == '1':
                window.blit(dirt_image, (x \* TILE_SIZE, y \* TILE_SIZE))
                block_list.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
            if tile == '2':
                window.blit(grass_image, (x \* TILE_SIZE, y \* TILE_SIZE))
                block_list.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
            if tile != '0':
                tile_rect.append(pygame.Rect(x \* TILE_SIZE, y \* TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    speed = 5 \* dt
    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if userInput\[pygame.K_w\] and up is True:
        player.up(speed)
    if userInput\[pygame.K_s\] and down is True:
        player.down(speed)
    if userInput\[pygame.K_a\] and left is True:
        player.left(speed)
    if userInput\[pygame.K_d\] and right is True:
        player.right(speed)

    player_group.draw(window)
    player.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(10)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please correct the formatting of the code?

Comment: I dont know how.

Comment: So learn it. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Atleast you can remove the '\' from the  code

Comment: It is not allowing me to reformat it.

Comment: Of course you are allowed to edit your own question. If you can't do it, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The position of a block in the window is (`x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE`) instead of (`x, y`):

<s>`block_list.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))`</s>

```py
block_list.append(pygame.Rect(x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
```